# Given two real functions, $f$ and $g$, if $|f(x)|<1$ then $|g(f(x))|<g(1)$? Why?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

It seems trivial for a certain $x$ but can we say it for all x?

Comment: No. The values of $g$ "have nothing to do" with the values of $f$. For real proofs, see the answers.

Comment: Can you explain for which $x$ does this seem trivial?

Answer (score 4):

This is false. Let $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 0$.

Comment: Or $g(x)=1-x$ to drive the point home.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem trivial for any $x$ infact. If $f(x)<1 $ and $ g(x) > g(1) $ for $ x < 1$, Then the condition fails.

Answer (score 1):

Also take $f=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ and $g=\frac{1}{t}$